# CompareTo Mthod, sort a list

Tags: java

i have a question, i want to sort a list.
I want to write a compareTo mthod, but I want to asign to variable to the compareTo method, like this

```
public int compareTo(Object object, LinkedList<Integer> list) {
...
}
```

is it possible to do this?
Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use the override comparteTo- method and the variable as field from the class.

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot change the method signature of an abstract method in `Comparable` interface. While implementing `Comparable` interface, you need to implement

```
int compareTo(T o)
```

Comment: oh is there an other possibility?

Comment: I'd recommend that you need to revisit your design of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Comparable interface if you want to use the build in sort functions.

So the the answer would be no.  If you want to have access to an extra objecct have that as a variable in the class.

Comment: I did it like that, but it doesn't work... the second list is filled in an other class and if I want to have the second list it is empty

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what cooperators are for?

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1 - o2;
        }
    });
```

Comment: the problem is I need the other list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` implementing `Comparable` interface in the same class:

```
class A implements Comparable<Integer> {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Integer o) {
       return compareTo(o, list);
    }

    private int compareTo(Integer o, List<Integer> list) {
        return ...; // Your comparison here
    }


}
```

Comment: why two methods? you can use the list in first method.

Comment: Of course yes. It is only for demonstration possibility what was desired.